# How can I make subfolders of subfolders?

Tags: vba

I have a directory that has 1000's of files. The filename string goes like: `ManagerName_EmployeeName_First Assessment.xlsx`

but I have a specific type of grouping I need to execute so that I have folders go by `ManagerName` > `Employee Name` and then the 5 types of Assessments in the employees folder.

How would I edit this to identify the first `_` in the filename (ManagerName) and then make a folder by that `ManagerName` and then make a subfolder by `EmployeeName` and then house all five files under that employee in the employee subfolder?

I know you'd need to use a `Left(fileName, InStrRev(fileName, "_") > 1)` type function to identify the first text string to the left of the first `_` but how would I go and create a second subfolder based on the employee under that manager?

Here's a shell of the code I was thinking:

```
Option Explicit
Sub MoveFiles()

Dim objFSO          As Object
Dim objMyFolder     As Object
Dim objMyFile       As Object
Dim strSourceFolder As String
Dim strDestFolder   As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strSourceFolder = "C:\Users\CIB\"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objMyFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strSourceFolder)

For Each objMyFile In objMyFolder.Files

    Do While objMyFile <> ""

        strDestFolder = Left(objMyFile.Name, InStrRev(objMyFile, "_") - 1)
        If Len(Dir(strDestFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir strDestFolder
        End If

        FileCopy strSourceFolder & "\" & objMyFile.Name, strDestFolder & "\" & objMyFile.Name

        Kill strSourceFolder & "\" & objMyFile.Name

    Loop

Next objMyFile

Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objMyFolder = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If the names are consistent then you should consider using Split() to create an array to loop over to create/locate the folders and final location.

Comment: You should generally try to avoid using VBA filesystem handling function mixed in with `Scripting.FileSystemObject` handling. I.e., [`CreateFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createfolder-method) instead of `MkDir`, [`MoveFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/movefile-method) instead of `FileCopy`, [`DeleteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/deletefile-method) instead of `Kill`, etc.

Comment: You can also use `InStrRev` or `InStr` function in a loop, passing [start] parameter +1 to previous number.

Comment: @TimWilliams Names will always be consistent and separated by `_`'s, but I've never used the Split function before. Is that easy to incorporate into the pre-existing code or is this a whole new thing I have to create in a separate module?

Comment: @MaciejLos so I updated my code to search for the first `_` and MkDir based on that string, but it doesn't make the folder. Any idea why?

Comment: You have to check what is in a `strDestFolder` variable. Use `[F8]` to run a code in step by step mode and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed your code accordingly to [TimWiliams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) suggestions:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveFiles()

    Dim objFSO          As Object
    Dim objMyFolder     As Object
    Dim objMyFile       As Object
    Dim strSourceFolder As String
    Dim strDestFolder   As String
    Dim parts() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    strSourceFolder = "C:\Users\CIB\"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objMyFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strSourceFolder)

    For Each objMyFile In objMyFolder.Files

        If objMyFile Is Nothing Then GoTo SkipNext

        parts = Split(objMyFile.Name, "_")
        strDestFolder = strSourceFolder
        For i = LBound(parts) To UBound(parts) - 1
            strDestFolder = strDestFolder & parts(i) & "\"
            'if path does not exists, create it
            If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strDestFolder) Then objFSO.CreateFolder strDestFolder

        FileCopy strSourceFolder & "\" & objMyFile.Name, strDestFolder & "\" & objMyFile.Name
        Kill strSourceFolder & "\" & objMyFile.Name
        strDestFolder = ""

        SkipNext:
    Next objMyFile

    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objMyFolder = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you use `Dir(path) = ""` when the FSO has a perfectly good [FolderExists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/folderexists-method) method? Using `Dir` will break any calling code that ***also*** uses `Dir` because it has global state. Using it when you already have an FSO available is sort of pointless.

Comment: @Comintern, thanks for your valuable comment. Changed.

Comment: @MaciejLos it says the `Path` variable is not defined, would I just put `Dim Path As String`?

Comment: @MaciejLos ok, it's working to create the folders, but now the file isn't being copied and placed in that folder. Any ideas? It's now just creating the folders but not moving them to their destFolder

EDIT: It's displaying `strDestFolder = ""` when I hover over the variable

Comment: Super! Let's remove all unnecessary comments.